# Do I have to install rails for every MAC OSX users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, installation

I am running Mac OSX 10.9 Maverick. I have install rails 4 for 1 admin user. then i created another user which is again admin. It's working fine for first user but for second user I am getting following error

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

I also tried to run command it gave in error but then i got another error.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
```

My question is that do I have to install rails for every MAC OSX Users?
If not then how to install rails globally for every users.
If I have to install for every users then why I am getting above error?

Comment: What do you mean by "users" in this context?  Do you mean "other devs on your project team"?

Comment: No i mean MAC users. I have 2 users in Mac OSX 10.9. I have installed rails on first user. for second user it shows error. rest of the details are in question

Comment: I got that.  But, what is a "user"?  I mean, my wife has a Macbook Air but i assume you're not talking about her.

Comment: See I have mac. which i am using as well as my brother is using. So we both wants rails access on local. so I installed rails via my user which is razor and I let him use rails as well. but he got error.

Comment: So by "user" you mean "different user accounts on the same machine".  I see....

Comment: Yes any idea for problem i am facing?

Comment: I would recommend using RVM, and have a look at the "Multi-user" && "Mixed mode installation" on this page http://rvm.io/rvm/install